# How to hash a file to determine if I already see it or not

Tags: java, file, hash

I am develop a web app (using Java EE 6 with GF 3.1) that allow user to upload a pdf file. Since this is a closed small community, there are lots of chances that the uploaded file is already in the system. I cant just check name for duplication since it is clearly not enough. I was thinking about hash the entire file and store the entry inside a database. Is this feasible and how to achieve this? If not, then what is a better way.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. File uploads should not be too common, and a hash computation is only done once, and is not that computation intensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using checksum.

This is from http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/CalculateChecksum.html

```
byte[] bytes = "some data".getBytes();

// Compute Adler-32 checksum
Checksum checksumEngine = new Adler32();
checksumEngine.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
long checksum = checksumEngine.getValue();

// Compute CRC-32 checksum
checksumEngine = new CRC32();
checksumEngine.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
checksum = checksumEngine.getValue();

// The checksum engine can be reused again for a different byte array by calling reset()
checksumEngine.reset();
```

**Edit**:

Be aware that checksums cannot absolutely tell you if two files are different, but they're very useful.

If two files are the same, they *will* have the same checksum.

So if the checksums differ, you know absolutely that the files differ.

But two different files can also sometimes have the same checksum.

So the way to use this is to calculate the checksums first - if they differ, the files are different.  If they're the same, you'll have to do a byte-by-byte comparison.  That's slower, of course, but it won't happen often.

**Note also** all of this applies to hashcodes as well.

Comment: +1 for not suggesting a secure hash here, CRC32 is faster and security is not of the essence for the problem.

Comment: @Harry - yes and no.  Yes, checksum guarantees uniqueness: if two files yield different checksums, the files are different.  But the reverse is not true: two different files may have different checksums (the same is true for hashing or any other characterization method which results in a value smaller than the originals).

Comment: @emboss - thanks, I agree about speed and the lack of need for security in this case.

Comment: @RMT - thanks for the edit.  Pity there's no way to upvote edits.

Comment: @CPerkins: so two different files may have the same checksum? That is a bit bad. If I hash the file with SHA-256 instead of MD5, does it guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: @Harry - no. Checksums _will_ tell you that they're different, but nothing like a hash or checksum can possibly tell you that two files are the same. This is hard in comments. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is pretty elegant. Compute hash of the file content (MD5 might be enough for start) and use it as a primary key in the database. You might save the file in the database as well or somewhere externally (lots of controversies about that).

Next time somebody uploads the file, compute the hash, check the database, save if not there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's feasible. In fact, that's what P2P programs do to identify a file.

Use any cryptographic hash algorithm (MD5, SHA-1, etc.)

Java has support for hashes using the [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class.

Note however than this will allow you to avoid storing duplicate files, but it won't prevent users from uploading the file: it's only at server side that you'll be able to access the file contents and hash it, unless you use an applet or webstart app with the privilege to access local files.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's feasible, you can use the [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class to do this.  For example:

```
InputStream is = // input stream of the uploaded file
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
byte[] digest;
try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    for (int count = is.read(buffer); count != -1; count = is.read(buffer)) {
        md.update(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    digest = md.digest();
    // store digest as needed, possibly Base64 encode first
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    // handle
}
```

Comment: Does MD5 hash on files guarantee uniqueness -> if two hashes are different than, the two files are different and vice versa. If not so, then does switch from Md5 to SHA-256 would help increase chance of uniqueness?

Comment: It doesn't _guarantee_ uniqueness, no hash function can do that, but the odds of a collision are low. SHA is going to have an even lower chance of collision, but computing the SHA hash will take longer than computing the MD5 hash. Having said that, CRC is probably a better choice, as pointed out by CPerkins, given that you don't need a secure hash.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have used Timothy W Macinta's (might be SO User @Tim Macinta) ["Fast MD5 Implementation"](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php).

The simplest example is:

```
// imports: java.io.File and com.twmacinta.util.MD5;

String hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(new File(filename)));
```

This utility also has the ability to use a native library for improved performance.

Comment: Does MD5 hash on files guarantee uniqueness -> if two hashes are different than, the two files are different and vice versa. If not so, then does switch from Md5 to SHA-256 would help increase chance of uniqueness?